# Sort or find messages by "date deleted" in Thunderbird Trash folder

Tags: thunderbird, 23.10

Assume that I had a quite old message in my **Inbox** (or any other folder) and *just deleted it*. It will go into my **Trash** folder.

How can I sort my **Trash** folder so that the message I deleted right now appears on the top or bottom of the message list in the Trash folder? A sort criterion something like "Date Deleted" will be need, but there is none.

---

<sub>Please, feel free to advise me to migrate this question to another more appropriate **StackExchange** site.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do set the `Order Received` filter from the filters in `Trash` page and it shows them as sorted by delete orders. So, the latest deleted message is at the top when sorting descending. By default, the latest deleted one is at the bottom:

[image]

Hope, it's clear and useful

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that! That was what I wanted indeed!

Comment: Glad it's useful!